# Aviso en Chrome: envío cancelado porque el formulario no está conectado

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Tengo un botón que ejecuta una función para crear un PDF, súbitamente dejó de funcionar y el inspeccionador solo me arroja este Warning:

> Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Anexo el código:

```
function ReporRepo() {

    var formulario;

    formulario = '<form action="GenPDF/ReposicionPDF.php"  target="ventanaForm"  method="post" onsubmit="$(\'#caja1\').dialog(\'destroy\');">\
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">\
                    <tr>\
                        <td>Reporte:</td>\
                        <td><select class="form-control" name="Repor">\
                                <option value="1">Reposicion NO Realizada</option>\
                                <option value="2">Reposicion Realizada</option>\
                        </select></td>\
                        <tr><td>Desde:</td><td><input name="FechaD" id="Desde" type="text" class="desdeF form-control" required/></td></tr>\
                        <tr><td>Hasta:</td><td><input name="FechaH" id="Hasta" type="text" class="hastaF form-control" required/></td></tr>\
                        <tr><td colspan="2"><input  type="submit" value="Generar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"/> <input type="reset"  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Limpiar"></td></tr>\
                    </tr>\
                </table>\
            </form>';
    cajaText('caja1', 'Reporte Reposicion', formulario);
    MaskAgrRegistro();
}
```

Comment: por que no agregas una modal que te realize ese codigo sin tener que escribirlo con PHP

Comment: intenta generar por un servicio el archivo , al generarlo agrega un link de descarga que tiene la url del archivo

Comment: Para generar el PDF necesito pasar parametros (fechas y tipo de reporte), y mi codigo estaba funcionando, incluso en microsoft edge funciona perfectamente, pero en chrome o mozilla me arroja el warning

Comment: entiendo... intenta lo que te comente en el segundo comentario. cuando genere el archivo devuelve un link de descarga, y con javascript dale automaticamente click yo lo he hecho en proyectos anteriores y me funciona muy bien

Comment: y qué hace la función cajaText?

Comment: es una función para armar una ventana modal por js

Comment: ¿Este error ocurre sólo en Chrome o también en otros navegadores?¿Puedes crear un [mcve] en el que podamos ver el fallo?

Answer (score 1):

**Según el estandar HTML**

> If form document is not connected, has no associated browsing context,
>   or its active sandboxing flag set has its sandboxed forms browsing
>   context flag set, then abort these steps without doing anything.

Que viene a decir que si no está añadido al contexto del navegador se abortara cualquier operación. Para solucionar esto solo tienes que añadir el formulario al contexto:

```
document.body.appendChild(formulario);
```

Comment: Gracias! pero ya eso lo he intentado, por eso anexe el código, quisiera saber si lo estoy agregando mal, si vez, yo armo el formulario con una pequeña función...

Answer (score 0):

Listo! ya lo solucione, cree todo el formulario en una ventana modal de bootstrap...

Y ahora si me funciona en todos los navegadores, Gracias por los aportes..